# Find $l$ of an oblique cone, based on $r, \alpha$ and $\beta$

Tags: geometry

I am trying to find $l$ of an oblique cone, but the only variables that I have at the moment are $r, \alpha$ and $\beta$. I am not sure if it is even possible.

[image: Oblique Cone]

Edit: Thanks to @Bernards answer I managed to come up with this:

\begin{align*}
h & =l\sin\alpha=m\sin\beta \\
m& = l\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
r^2 &= l^2 + \left(l\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}\right)^2-2l\left(l\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}\right)\cos(\beta-\alpha) \\
r^2 &= l^2 + l^2\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin^2\beta}-2l^2\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}\cos(\beta-\alpha) \\
l &= \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{1+\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin^2\beta}-2\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}\cos({\beta-\alpha})}}
\end{align*}

Comment: $\frac{\ell}{\sin(180^\circ-\beta)} = \frac{r}{\sin(\beta-\alpha)}$

Comment: Your edited formula reduces to $$\ell = \frac{r \sin\beta}{\sin(\beta-\alpha)}$$ which matches the solution in my comment. I'll note here that the formula I gave is simply an application of the Law of Sines to your figure's $\ell$-$r$-$m$ triangle, which has angle $180^\circ-\beta$ opposite $\ell$ and angle $\beta-\alpha$ opposite $r$.

Comment: @Blue Oh, yeah I just realized that. Although, for your formula, it sometimes yields negative results ... whereas for the edited formula, it always seems to stay positive.

Comment: Negatives shouldn't appear. (Taking $\alpha$ & $\beta$ on the "same side" of $\ell$...) Angle $\beta$, as an "exterior" angle of the triangle, is never smaller than either "remote interior" angle, eg $\alpha$; thus, $\beta-\alpha \geq 0$, so $\sin(\beta-\alpha)\geq 0$. Since $\sin\beta \geq 0$, too, the result is non-negative. Note: In your solution, going from $\ell^2 = \text{stuff}$ to $\ell = \sqrt{\text{stuff}}$ *should* introduce a $\pm$. Your formula "always seems to stay positive" simply because you've *chosen* the positive square root, effectively wrapping my soln in an absolute value.

Comment: Ah, I think I got confused. The angles $\alpha, \beta$ define how the cone is tilted? I thought $\beta$ was the angle between $d$ and $m$ and $\alpha$ was the angle between $d$ and $l$.

Comment: My interpretation of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ agrees with yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can, starting from the equations
$$h=l\sin\alpha=m\sin\beta,$$
and using Al Kashi's relation:
$$r^2=l^2+m^2-2lm\cos(\beta-\alpha).$$
There remains to eliminate $m$ to obtain an equation in $l$.

Comment: But how would I eliminate $m$ from the equation, given the fact I neither know $l$ nor $m$?

Comment: With the first equations: $\; m\sin\beta=l\sin\alpha$, so you can express $m$ as a function of $l,α,β$.

Comment: Alright, I think I came up with something. I edited it into the post, any idea if that can be further simplified? :)

Comment: Blue's comment above gives the final simplification